# Mapping List of Object From Parent Object which has a List of Objects

Tags: java-8, mapstruct

I am trying to use mapstruct to transform an object as below

**Source**

```
MainObject
{

    String key;
    List<ChildObject> children;
}

ChildObject{

    String childVar1;
    String childVar2;

}
```

**Target**

```
List<TargetObj> targetObjects;

TargetObj{

    String key;
    String var1;
    String var2;

}
```

I need to prepare a list of TargetObj instances with the key mapped from the key from MainObject and var1 and var2 mapped from ChildObject.
I tried to use ObjectFactory and Decorator as mentioned in the mapstruct documentation. But couldn't find a way to get this done. Both cases I got an error which states cannot return iterable object from non iterable parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use a combination of `@BeforeMapping` or `@AfterMapping` with the `@Context`.

Your mapper can look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default List<TargetObj> map(MainObject source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList(); // or null or whatever you prefer 
        }
        return map(source.getChildren(), new CustomContext(source));
    }

    List<TargetObject> map(List<ChildObject> children, @Context CustomContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "key", ignore = true) // key is mapped in the context
    TargetObject map(ChildObject child, @Context CustomContext context);
}
```

And the custom context would look something like:

```
public class CustomContext {

    protected final MainObject mainObject;

    public CustomContext(MainObject mainObject) {
        this.mainObject = mainObject;
    }

    @AfterMapping // of @BeforeMapping
    public void afterChild(@MappingTarget ChildObject child) {
        child.setKey(mainObject.getKey());
        // More complex mappings if needed
    }
}
```

The goal is to do manual mapping from your `MainObject` to the `List<TargetObj>` by using other methods that MapStruct will generate

Comment: I need to do this, but backwards where MainObject would be the target, and the other the source, @filip, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Please create a new question